# checking for keyboard input while waiting for button input

Tags: python, string

I'm having some trouble with my script. I want to implement a way to close my script with a string. The thing is, I don't want to wait for keyboard input. Instead, I want to check if something has been input through the keyboard while the script is waiting for a button to be pressed. I'm playing around with a Raspberry Pi. I've connected a LED to i's GPIO and a switch to light up the LED.

Here's the working code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)

while Truue:
    value = GPIO.input(8)

    if value == False:
        GPIO.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)
        print("Button pressed")

        while value == False:
            value = GPIO.input(8)
    else:
        GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)
```

The LED lights up when the button is pressed, and turns off when button is released. It's in an infinite loop waiting for button response. What I want to do is while the script is waiting for button input, and I input "exit" from keyboard, the script stops.

Comment: Have you seen that there is a Raspberry PI Stack Exchange? Your question is perfectly on-topic here, but on that site you probably find a lot more concentrated R-Pi expertise to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using Python 3, so:

```
exit = False
while not exit:
    value = GPIO.input(8)
    entered = input('type exit to stop: ')
    if not value:
        print("Button Pressed")
        GPIO.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)
    if entered == 'exit':
        break
```

For conditionals - it is more idomatic to us `not exit` than `exit == False`

If you were using Python 2.x, you would use the built in function `raw_input` instead of `input`.